# How many master pages can an application have?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I would like to know how many master pages can an application have?

Comment: Check out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284572/can-i-have-multiple-site-master-files-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1):

As many as you want/as many as you need. There isn't a limit for this, why should there be..

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific limit on the number of master pages, as you just reference them by file name.

If you have several thousands of them, or perhaps millions, you might run into some space limitations...

Answer (score 0):

Application? Unlimited.
Page? One (can be inherited).